# p2.inf Filtering in Tycho when building an RCP application

Tags: rcp, p2, tycho

I´m building an RCP application using tycho. The RCP application uses p2 and its self updateable capabilities configuring the respository in an p2.inf file. Works like a charm.

Now I want to introduce a placeholder ${updatesiteurl} in the p2.inf file and replace it with the URL according to the environment for which it is built. But unforunately it get´s replaced with an empty string instead of the environment variable which I guess happens because tycho, or the p2 director, replaces some escaped characters (like the ":" which is ${58} for example).

Any ideas how this could be solved? I thought about explicitly declaring the resource plugin and binding it to an earlier build phase but that didn´t work either...

Comment: How did you get your RCP application to be updateable.  Any features that I include in my target I can't update.  It seems related to this bug: [361722](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361722)  I was just wondering how you worked around it.

Comment: I basically followed this guide: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application - I´m not aware of the bug you linked here, but maybe we will discover this soon, because I´m about to add a VM to the installation as a feature to be able to update the VM with the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What finally worked is: I moved the p2.inf file to directory /p2 and let the maven resource plugin copy the file with the replacements to a temporary folder in /target. Now a copy task copies the file in a later phase (why the hell didn´t this work in the same phase...) to the the root directory, where the .product file is, since both have to be in the same directory (with the same prefix). Finally `clean` deletes the p2.inf file in the root directory...

Comment: Good solution - though it is peculiar that the packaging mojo for features cannot find the p2.inf in the target directory.... That would really help!

Comment: Maybe this has been fixed/changed in the recent time, it's been a while since I came up with the solution. I'm not working on eclipse stuff anymore (sad music sets in...)

Comment: Unfortunately, the code that reads and applies the p2.inf file is found in the p2 part of the solution - not in the Maven/Tycho part. So it does not know about alternative locations, etc...